# Running a service before log in

Tags: fedora, systemd, startup

I don't like opening a question here for such a, seemingly, simple issue; but I've been stuck on this for a while now and I have no idea what to do next.

I'm running a Fedora 22 system on a development board, and I want to run a file (For the sake of simplicity, that file is just a compiled.c that prints "Hello World") called start, so it's address is `/root/start`.

So I've gone to `/lib/systemd/system` and created `start.service`, which contains the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=System Start

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/
type=simple
ExecStart=/root/start
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that, I ran `systemctl enable start.service`. The problem is, it's doing nothing, and even if I try to run `systemctl start start.service`, it won't do a thing.

Any pointers you could give me would be really helpful.

Comment: where do you expect it to print the *Hello World* message? To your terminal or something? In that case you probably shouldn't be looking at system services, and either want to look at the user sessions or loginctl.

Comment: Yeah, I want to have it printed to the terminal. I'll check what you told me :)

Comment: your session begins at login, and if you do that in a console, then your thing may be as simple as an extra line in `~/.profile`.

Comment: But wouldn't these start after login?

Comment: yes. that's when your display session starts, too. what exactly are you looking for? you wanna do like a wall message before anyone logs in? in that case, you *do* need to be looking at system services, but also you should specify what you want.

Comment: I want to execute a code written in C before a user logs in, this code makes use of some of the board GPIO pins, but I guessed I could start with making it just print a Hello World to the terminal.

Comment: ok, then you need a system service - a *one-shot* type if youre using systemd - and if you want it to display on a screen then you need to make it depend on the graphical something-or-other target, and you'll need to explicitly link it to the login console... i forget how its done... ill check the man pages and see if i can hunt it down for you...

Comment: i guess you just want to do something in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` and probably to look [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html)...

Comment: `StandardOutput=journal+console` ?

Comment: Whew, I'm a bit lost now.

If i understood correctly, the problem here is that the terminal won't be initialized until I log in.

If that's correct, why doesn't `systemctl start start.service` work either?